# PHP MySQL problem

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

Whenever I try to run a php script on my website hosted by hostgator, I get this error:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Unknown MySQL server host 'pieboy13_(user name)' (1) in /home/pieboy13/public_html/quigley/WebContent/Scripts/register.php on line 6
>   Error: Could not connect to server. Error Unknown MySQL server host 'pieboy13_(user name)' (1)

Where (Username) is my username.

What could cause this?

Comment: Please include your code from register.php. Especially the first 10 lines.

Answer (score 7):

You are triying to connect to your username! Check your configuration for server url and make sure it points to your mysql server.

Comment: Yay! You guys really helped! Me and one of my somewhat beginners friends had been stumped over that for about half an hour! Gotta read those docs better, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Things that can cause this:

1. You are using the wrong hostname for the mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have put your database or username into the server argument.